# Allow php value to only work in a subdirectory

Tags: php, nginx, nginx-config

In my php.ini, I have disabled allow_url_fopen. I would like to enable it for my /example directory as shown below, but it does not work. However, if I move the directive to allow it from /example to the ~.php$ location above it, then it works fine. I'm thinking that the /example location block is never processed. Any ideas how to allow url fopen to work only in the /example directory?

```
server {
  location ~\.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    include fastcgi_params;
  }

  location /example {
    fastcgi_param PHP_ADMIN_VALUE "allow_url_fopen=1";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`nginx` chooses one `location` to process the request. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html) for details.

The *regular expression* `location` block takes precedence over regular *prefix* `location` blocks, so any URI ending with `.php` will be processed by your `location ~\.php$` block, irrespective of whether or not it begins with `/example`. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.

If you want to create a `location` that sends additional fastcgi parameters, you will need to include all required fastcgi directives.

For example:

```
location ~\.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    include fastcgi_params;
}

location ^~ /example {
    location ~\.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param PHP_ADMIN_VALUE "allow_url_fopen=1";
    }
}
```